# remove line breaks fails

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove string line breaks,
and i am getting the exact string.

this is my code

```
function removeBreaks(string){
   let functionString = string.substring(7, string.length);
   let cleanFunction = functionString.replace(/\r?\n|\r/gm, '');
   console.log(cleanFunction);
}

let string = "dksldt: function (global){\n var o = {id:l._id, z: s, t:o};\n  return o; \n} "
removeBreaks(string);


//output: "dhslkf: function (global){\n var o = {id:l._id, z: s, t:o};\n  return o; \n}"
```

but when im doing:

```
"function (global){\n var o = {id:l._id, z: s, t:o};\n  return o; \n}".replace(/\r?\n|\r/gm, '');
//output: "function (global){ var o = {id:l._id, z: s, t:o};  return o; } "
```

in the console im getting the a good result.

Comment: functionString.split('\n').join('')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your regex is wrong, because you forgot escaping slash before `\n`:

```
functionString.replace(/\r?\\n|\r/gm, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cleanFunction.split('\n').join('')
```

Comment: idk why but it didnt work for me...
i will go with @steppefox.
but thank you.